# Fridge won’t stop running

Tags: electrical, refrigerator

My fridge won’t stop running. (*Model #596.69272990, noted below*)

This has been ongoing for a week and I have not tried to do anything other than unplug it and plug it back in.

Is it the relay and if so how do I change it?

[image: Model]

Comment: Not enough information to provide an informed answer. What have you tried?  How long has it been running?   Please add Any other info that may be useful.

Comment: What relay?    Have you looked up the service manual or the schematics for it online? Have you searched for others with this problem online?  It is unlikely we can diagnose it from here.

Comment: I could not find anything online and am just asking if folks have had the same issue and how they have fixed it.

Comment: I'd check the thermostat first and also for ice on the evaporator coils.  That can clog up the airflow and prevent the refrigerator section from getting cold enough to shut off the compressor.

Comment: https://www.repairclinic.com/ProductDetail/504029

Comment: Your fridge may be low on Freon and struggling to maintain temperature, or heat exchanger coils are dirty and not transferring enough heat so the compressor continues to run. First measure the temp try turning the temp down is the temp following the adjustment? With the thermostat turned down did the compressor stop? We don’t go in and just start changing parts.

Comment: @EdBeal think you